# Cannot stat install-recovery.sh when building CM 13

Tags: android, android-source, android-build, cyanogenmod, lineageos

I'm trying to run CyanogenMod 13 (Android 6.0) on an old Wiko Highway 4G (Android 4.4.2, Tegra 4i) but when I build with [my device tree](https://github.com/goofyahhphones/android_device_wiko_s9321/tree/cm-13.0), I get an error that tells me:

cp: cannot stat '/home/user/android/cm/out/target/product/s9321/ota_temp/SYSTEM/bin/install-recovery.sh'
make: *** [build/core/Makefile:1104: /home/user/android/cm/out/target/product/s9321/system/bin/install-recovery.sh] Error 1

This is weird because:

1. install-recovery.sh should be located at /system/etc and not bin
2. I found the init file refering to this script in my tree and tried to remove it but I still get this error so the issue shouldn't come from my tree

Please, does anyone know the solution? I've been searching for a day.

Thanks in advance